# Transitioning letter-spacing on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I was wondering if someone can confirm that Chrome doesn't support transitioning the `letter-spacing` property. I wasn't able to find any documentation on this, but it doesn't seem to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/gjJwz/

That example works as expected for me in Firefox, but in Chrome 28.0.1500.95, the change is abrupt (no transition). I'm testing on Windows 7.

Comment: It is somewhat animated if you add more spacing i.e: 2px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase your `letter-spacing and you'll see it

```
a:hover {
    letter-spacing: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gjJwz/1/

Comment: Yep, I see it now. I guess this has something to do with Chrome's [subpixel rendering issue](http://bricss.net/post/22718920352/subpixel-layout-coming-to-webkit). Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Um, it works fine for me, I'm using the same version of chrome. Keep in mind that you can't gradually get to 1px of letter spacing, it would have to be a bigger value to ease in.